# How can I clean windows and gutters from a ladder in a narrow side yard?

Tags: ladder

I want to clean out my 2nd story gutters and wash windows, but my side yard is about 5 feet between house and fence.  Considering the overhang, there's probably 4 feet of horizontal I'd prefer not to get on the roof, since it's a steep pitch.

Gutters are at 19'.  Fence to brick is 4'4".

What options do I have to securely access the gutters?  I currently do not have a ladder that tall, so I am starting from scratch when it comes to the configuration.

[image]

Comment: My approach to this situation would be to use a pole-mounted window brush and hire someone to clean the gutters.

Comment: You are at least 14' up in the air (assume the lower level 4' in height). I would hire a professional to do it for safety alone.  Though it would cost you.

Comment: you could try making a vacuum cleaner nozzle for a shop vac that reaches into the gutter ... something shaped like a candy cane ... use white pvc pipe

Comment: They actually sell a J shaped nozzle for this.  I vacuum my gutter out twice a year.  Works great.  In this case, extra extension pieces would be needed.

Answer (score 1):

Talk with your neighbor to see if you can place your long ladder onto their property for the cleaning. Hopefully the ladder would just touch the top of the fence. At the bottom you may need plywood pads and even a rope tie from the bottom rung to the fence using a screw eye.

Comment: Use the neighbor's yard. Take the fence down. Or use a folded step ladder propped against the fence to get on to an extension ladder propped precariously against the gutter. If someone hung themselves on the underside for me, I'd go up it no problem, but I'm also more physically fit than 99% of the world's population so YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the gutter, I would pay to have this professionally done.  I would have a LeafGuard installed over the gutter so that there would not be a need to do this annually.

Regarding the windows, I would use a soft mop on a long pole followed by a squeegie that is also on a long pole.

Answer (score 1):

There is a shop vaccuum kit for cleaning gutters from RIDGID.
Home Depot sell it.

https://www.homedepot.com/p/RIDGID-2-1-2-in-Gutter-Cleaning-Accessory-Kit-for-RIDGID-Wet-Dry-Shop-Vacuums-VT2515/203235222

Answer (score -1):

Don't use a ladder. Get up on the roof at a more comfortable and safe location, and clean the gutters from above. Big Blue and Big Orange both sell fall protection kits for roof work for $99.

Comment: How would I access the window to clean it?

Comment: Also the roof is steeply pitched.

Comment: I'm not against the advice, not sure why you got downvoted.  Just explaining all the parameters.

Comment: Ah. I missed the part about the windows. That's probably why the downvotes.

Comment: Personally, I would probably still clean the gutters from the roof and clean the windows with a long brush or s magnetic window cleaner.